# How to plot graph of acceleration in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Suppose a body is moving with a constant velocity of 5 m/s in positive x direction.

Now after some time it changes it's direction from +x to +y keeping the magnitude same.

And it keep doing that motion i.e changing it's direction from +x to +y

Now how can i represent this motion graphically in a $v_{net}$-t graph.

The v-t graph will show that the body is not accelerating as it v-t graph will just be a horizontal line but i just showed that it does.
Where am I wrong?

Now suppose a horizontal  v-t graph is given. Is it possible to tell whether the object was accelerating or not?

V means Velocity here.

+x and +y is the plane in which my hypothetical object is moving.

Comment: By V-t graph are you referring to the velocity time graph or the speed time graph ?

Comment: Velocity-time graph

Comment: And do you mean that it first moves in the + x axis then + y and then + x and then +y continuously switching between the 2

Comment: Not continuously,  after say  10 seconds the object changes direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably denote the *absolute* value of the velocity by $v_{net} = |\vec v|$. Why don't you plot each velocity component of the vector $(v_x, v_y)$ separately. This would describe the situation much better.

[image]

Please note, unless you tell use the time interval during which the acceleration takes it is impossible to calc the acceleration. As the time interval approached zero, $\Delta t \to 0$, the acceleration approaches a [Dirac $\delta$-function](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-Distribution).

Comment: Can the time interval be 0? (Hypothetically)

Comment: I added the link to the wiki article of the Dirac delta fct. Please read it. Although this fct is unphysical, it is **often** used in models to describe key elements of physics. Therefore, the answer to your question depends on the assumption your are willing to make. E.g. if we assume that it is possible to have an infinite acceleration, and if we assume that the particle is able to withstand such a force without bursting into parts, the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 1):

(1) "The v-t graph will show that the body is not accelerating" The body *is* accelerating because its velocity is changing even though its speed is constant.

(2) "Now suppose a horizontal v-t graph is given. Is it possible to tell whether the object was accelerating or not?" I assume that $v$ is the body's speed (that is the magnitude of its velocity). You would *not* be able to tell from that graph whether or not the body was changing direction and therefore you would not be able to tell if it had acceleration due to change of direction.

(3) You could plot a graph of the angle to the North in which the body is heading against time. This wouldn't be a velocity-time graph, but it would give you information that you couldn't get from a speed-time graph. You could also plot graphs against time of the $x$ and $y$ components of the body's velocity.

Comment: V is velocity as the person said

Comment: The person *hadn't* said it when I wrote my answer!

Comment: @PhilipWood No offense sir but you should have clarified it first rather than assuming.

Comment: Maybe $you$ should have clarified it in your original question. As it was, you talked about a v-t graph so it seemed reasonable that the $v$ was the magnitude of the velocity (that is the speed) since you can't plot the velocity of a body whose direction is changing in two dimensions as a single variable.

Comment: "body whose direction is changing in two dimensions as a single variable.  Add this in your answer."This is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Ohw Please don't issue commands.

Comment: @PhilipWood Sorry sir , it was a sincere request.

Answer (score 0):

@Semoi's graph is correct for plotting velocity versus time.

Acceleration is the change in velocity. Many a times like when in uniform circular motion the speed remains constant but due to the change in the direction of velocity the body is said to be accelerating.

Same can be said for your case. Lets say that the body's initial velocity(at t= 0) was 5 m/s $\hat{i}$ and after 10 seconds(t =10s) its velocity changes to 5 m/s $\hat{j}$.

We can say that the average acceleration along x axis upto this point in time is $\frac{-1}{2} ~ms^2$

After another ten seconds have passed (t = 20s) the average acceleration along x axis would be $0 ~ms^2$. So you can see that the acceleration versus time graph would have several points of discontinuity. So we can see that the acceleration of the body is not continuous along any axis.

And for your last query : No, if you were given just a graph of the net velocity versus time you wouldn't be able to tell if the bod was accelerating